# limiting the number of udp packets in send queue

Tags: c, sockets

is there a way to limit the number of UDP packets in the send queue?!

like

```
setsockopt(SO_SOCK, SO_SND_QUEUE_DGRAMS, value, length)
```

if so, what would the behavior if the queue is full ?! dropping packets, or waiting for the queue to transmit the packets to network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the size of the *kernel* send socket buffer (in *bytes*), use `SO_SNDBUF`.

The default behavior is blocking, but you can modify this so the socket is non-blocking (with the `SOCK_NONBLOCK` option on the `socket` call). Otherwise, you could set `O_NONBLOCK` with an `fcntl` call.

Then, you'd get back an error code of `EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK` instead of blocking on your `send` call.

You can also use either `select` or `poll` syscalls to control waiting.

There are also `ioctl` calls to check the current number of bytes in the queue, such as `TIOCINQ` for the receive queue or `TIOCOUTQ` for the send queue.

Note that, again, because you're using UDP, none of the above would guarantee delivery through the network as any other node in the path could drop the packet(s). The above only guarantees that the originating node won't drop due to buffer overflow.

What is [usually] more useful is to increase the size of the corresponding *kernel* receive buffer with `SO_RCVBUF` to allow large bursts to be received without the kernel dropping as much. Because of UDP, this is *not* a guarantee that the local node will *not* drop anything, but it can limit the number of drops.